# Switch between different types of buttons

Tags: html, css

So I used a codepen to implement buttons into my homepage [here](https://novac.dev/x/home/). The buttons work, but the issue is now the `ToDo (+)` button on the right, and the `ToDo (x)` button which appears after adding one, also have the effect of the `button ToDo(+)`. Specifically, hovering over them has two parallel lines swing in from opposite ends. How do I separate them from each other so one doesn't affect the other? The specific css code is here:

```
button{
  background:#00000088;
  color:#fff;
  border:none;
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding:0 1em;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
  transition:800ms ease all;
  outline:none;
}
button:hover{
  background:#ffffff;
  color:#000;
}
button:before,button:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:3px;
  width:0;
  background: #bd818d;
  transition:400ms ease all;
}
button:after{
  right: inherit;
  top: 47px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 0;
}
button:hover:before,button:hover:after{
  width:100%;
  transition:800ms ease all;
}
```

Comment: Do realize that CSS code without the HTML has no meaning whatsoever. Please include the whole minimal example in the question, including the HTML.

Comment: @Roope The link to the site should be there, it's a bit long of a MVE but I'm editing the question to add it now.

Comment: Add ClassNames on your buttons to know how to style each differently. everything else that's common between those buttons can be accessed using button{}

Comment: That is not cool at all. Please visit www.w3schools.com  and read through their html elements and attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the problem is:

```
button{ /* YourStyle */}
```

This is telling your browser that it must apply `YourStyle` above everywhere where it sees a button element. And your browser, remains loyal and obeys your instructions. To solve this, you must give a `button` names that defines it.

Example:

```
<button class='todo add'></button>
<button class='todo close'></button>
```

Referencing these buttons with css:

```
/* When you want to reference all buttons */
button{} or .todo{}

/* When you wish to target the todo add only */
.todo.add{} or .add{}

/* When you wish to target the todo close only */
.todo.close{} or .close{}
```

try giving your buttons class names or id and referencing them from css styles.

Comment: Got it, added .link after all the buttons then class = "link" at the buttons and that separated them, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying styles to `button`, you can make use of classnames to give specific styles to separate buttons.
The classname containing common styles can be given to both, and the specific ones can be in their respective classnames.